# "'SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set."

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to learn the query syntax in the sandbox ( https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo )

```
SELECT food.id FROM food JOIN t in food.tags WHERE t.name = "oil"
```

This works, but what if I want to get the entire document, so I tried

```
SELECT food.* FROM food JOIN t in food.tags  WHERE t.name = "oil"
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM food JOIN t in food.tags  WHERE t.name = "oil"
```

and get the error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "severity": "Error",
      "location": {
        "start": 7,
        "end": 8
      },
      "code": "SC2040",
      "message": "'SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set."
    }
  ]
}
```

How does one get the entire document back?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want is:

```
SELECT VALUE food FROM food JOIN t in food.tags WHERE t.name = "oil"
```