# Is it possible to store and query Array Spatial Data in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Here is a sample document that we would like to store:

```
{
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
   "locations": [
        { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [1,1] },
        { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [2,2] }
   ]
}
```

The key feature of the document is that the "locations" property is an array of GeoJSON points.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies#index-paths) it is possible to define an indexing policy for the locations array.

However, it's not clear whether spatial queries such as `ST_WITHIN` can be used to search, for example, whether any of the points in the array fall within a certain radius of a specified point.

My question: Does CosmosDB support **indexing** and **querying** of spatial data when stored in an **array**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From private conversation with CosmosDB:

**Can it be indexed?**

> yes, you just need to index /locations/[]/? or /locations/*

**Can it be queried?**

> yes, you can query over an array of points by using a JOIN to unwind the array.

`SELECT * FROM c JOIN loc IN c.locations WHERE ST_DISTANCE(loc, @myLocation) < @distance`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more: `SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set.`

Comment: Ah, I don't understand why this is yet, but the answer (with no explanation) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41088941/1228288